# javascript new Array -> php array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page that has a bunch of tick boxes, these are identified with a name="a number".
When a button is clicked, I have an JavaScript function that creates a new array with the numbers of the boxes ticked. This gets sent to a page 'test.php'.

It returns:

```
Array
(
    [data] => [null,"47284","47282","47281","47280","47279","47278","47277","47276","47269"]
)
```

When I try and explode this array I get an array to string conversion error.

What am I doing wrong?

I need to get these numbers separated so I can do an SQL query for each.

JavaScript code:

```
<script>
var selected = new Array();

function showMessage() {
var selected = Array();

    $('input:checked').each(function() {
        selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
    });
    var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to send these emails again?');
    if(answer) {
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(selected);
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../test.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {data : jsonString}, 
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    })
    }
}
</script>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
$(function(){

    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectallsent").click(function () {
          $('.yes').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
    $("#selectallprogress").click(function () {
          $('.no').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    $(".yes").click(function(){

        if($(".yes").length == $(".yes:checked").length) {
            $("#selectallsent").prop("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectallsent").removeAttr("checked");
        }

    });
    $(".no").click(function(){

        if($(".no").length == $(".no:checked").length) {
            $("#selectallprogress").prop("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectallprogress").removeAttr("checked");
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

test.php code:

```
<?
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

I know that I need to do something more on the test.php page but I would like to know what that is.

Comment: you should be printing the `data` post var.

Comment: if youre trying to explode an array, theres your problem.  explode turns a string into an array.

Comment: so what would i need to do to split this array then ? im tired and confused, but i really need to get this done before i go to bed. thanks for help in advance

Comment: You're sending a JSON string. You need to `json_decode` it and you'll get a PHP array which you can manipulate any way you like. `$result = json_decode($_POST['data']); print_r($result);`

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to do ....

First one is to not stringify the selected object (jquery will deal with this for you)

```
function showMessage() {
var selected = Array();

    $('input:checked').each(function() {
        selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
    });
    var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to send these emails again?');
    if(answer) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../test.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {data : selected}, 
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    })
    }
}
```

Then on the PHP side you can just access the values via

```
print_r($_POST["data"]);
```

This will be an array of your inputs.

Comment: Thanks, both Orangepill & N.B both of these work can you just confirm that i can now do a sql query which uses `IN` from mysql maybe iim confusing myself or im just dumb but this does not seem possible

Comment: just `foreach ($_POST["data"] as $id) { /* do your query using $id */}` and you are good.

Comment: I considered using this, but as the user may be selecting multiple tick boxes, I feel using IN would be better as its doing 1 sql rather than 1 for each id

Comment: @fightapilotdean That would be more performat... just make sure you quote and  sanatize the array values ... array_map is useful for that. Then implode into you in clause.

Comment: I can't get anything to work using array_map, I'm doing something wrong, it will just have to wait until tommorow, thanks for the help